# How to do custom query in supabase postgresql?

Tags: supabase, supabase-database

How to do this query with supabase postgreSQL ?

```sql
SELECT Words.word, COUNT(audios.id) AS count
FROM Words 
LEFT OUTER JOIN audios ON audios.word_id = words.id
GROUP BY words.id ORDER BY count DESC;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would create a Postgres function and then call it with the `.rpc` method of the supabase-js library. You can read more about this in the [documentation](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/database/functions).